# AWS cognito social login throwing NotAuthorizedException:does not have identity providers configured React Native

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm using user pool. I have completed signup with email now trying to implement social login.
`I'm using Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: 'Google' })` for google and
`Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: 'Facebook' })` for facebook.
Here is my config for OAuth

```
oauth: {
            domain: '__domain__',
            clientID: '__client id __',
            scope: ['email', 'profile', 'openid'],
            redirectSignIn: 'myapp://oauth/',
            redirectSignOut: 'myapp://signout/',
            responseType: 'code'
          }
```

I have added google, Facebook id and secret in aws.

But in the hub listener, I'm getting the following error.

signIn_failure [NotAuthorizedException: Identity pool - * poolid * does not 
have identity providers configured.]
However, the users who tried login using facebook and google is registered and is showing in the user list.
I'm pretty much stuck at this point, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue, we had Identity pool setup added in the config, so I had to add the social login id's in the Identity pool id config setup in the AWS section.